# .htaccess redirect from subfolder to main domain with same permalink structure

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Current I just finished migrating a WordPress site with the url www.boingnet.com/purl/ for the WordPress install. After migrating to a new server and changing the url to www.boingnet.com I am looking for a way to redirect all traffic from the old site to the new site and keep all digital assets.

http://www.boingnet.com/purl/pricing/

would go to....

http://www.boingnet.com/pricing/

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Please show that you at least made some effort before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.boingnet\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^purl/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteRule ^purl/(.*) /$1 [R,L]
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Create `.htaccess` file in "**pricing**" folder ,  it contains those lines:

```
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule (.*)$ /purl/$1 [R=301,L]
```